# Why Kube state metrics only shows metrics related to the namespace where it is running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, kubernetes, prometheus

I have AWS EKS cluster with kube-state-metrics installed in a namespace called "monitoring". This installation is using service monitor and other components (see yaml files below).
In this cluster, there is also a prometheus agent running and selecting the kube-state-metrics service monitor.

kube-state-metrics is listed on Prometheus targets property but when I add a dashboard on Grafana to visualize these metrics, I can only see kube-state-metrics related to the "monitoring" namespace. EKS cluster has other namespaces and kube-state-metrics should display metrics for all of them.

I have a similar setup for Cadvisor and it works fine by showing metrics related to all namespaces.

Any idea why kube-state-metrics is showing only data related to the namespace it is running?

prometheus.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: agent
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  version: v2.39.1
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      component: prometheus-agent
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      monitoring: prometheus-agent
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 1Gi
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 1Gi
  replicas: 1
  logLevel: debug
  logFormat: logfmt
  scrapeInterval: 30s
  remoteWrite:
  - url: https://prometheus-workspace
    sigv4:
      region: us-east-1
    queueConfig:
      maxSamplesPerSend: 1000
      maxShards: 200
      capacity: 2500
  containers:
  - name: prometheus
    args:
    - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml
    - --storage.agent.path=/prometheus
    - --enable-feature=agent
    - --web.enable-lifecycle
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: role
            operator: In
            values:
            - monitoring
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
              operator: In
              values:
              - prometheus
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        weight: 100
```

kube-state-metrics:

service-monitor.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: kube-state-metrics
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    component: prometheus-agent
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
  endpoints:
  - port: http-metrics
```

service.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 2.6.0
  name: kube-state-metrics
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http-metrics
    port: 8080
    targetPort: http-metrics
  - name: telemetry
    port: 8081
    targetPort: telemetry
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
```

deployment.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 2.6.0
  name: kube-state-metrics
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: exporter
        app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 2.6.0
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      containers:
      - image: registry.k8s.io/kube-state-metrics/kube-state-metrics:v2.6.0
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: kube-state-metrics
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http-metrics
        - containerPort: 8081
          name: telemetry
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8081
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsUser: 65534
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: kube-state-metrics
```

cluster-role-binding.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 2.6.0
  name: kube-state-metrics
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kube-state-metrics
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kube-state-metrics
  namespace: monitoring
```

cluster-role.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 2.6.0
  name: kube-state-metrics
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - secrets
  - nodes
  - pods
  - services
  - serviceaccounts
  - resourcequotas
  - replicationcontrollers
  - limitranges
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  - persistentvolumes
  - namespaces
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - statefulsets
  - daemonsets
  - deployments
  - replicasets
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - batch
  resources:
  - cronjobs
  - jobs
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - autoscaling
  resources:
  - horizontalpodautoscalers
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - authentication.k8s.io
  resources:
  - tokenreviews
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - authorization.k8s.io
  resources:
  - subjectaccessreviews
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resources:
  - poddisruptionbudgets
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - certificates.k8s.io
  resources:
  - certificatesigningrequests
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - storage.k8s.io
  resources:
  - storageclasses
  - volumeattachments
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - admissionregistration.k8s.io
  resources:
  - mutatingwebhookconfigurations
  - validatingwebhookconfigurations
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - networkpolicies
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - coordination.k8s.io
  resources:
  - leases
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  resources:
  - clusterrolebindings
  - clusterroles
  - rolebindings
  - roles
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
```

service-account.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: kube-state-metrics
  namespace: monitoring
```